# Error while trying to open chrome python-selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

from selenium import webdriver

> > > driver = webdriver.Chrome()

ERROR:

Python 3.4.1 (default, Nov 12 2014, 13:34:29) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from selenium import webdriver
> > >       driver = webdriver.Chrome()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/users/shabshar/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in **init**
> > >           s

elf.service.start()
  File "/users/shabshar/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/users/shabshar/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Comment: Are you running on a desktop with a monitor or a server?

Comment: I am running on xdm server